# Google cloud storage java - How to give access to a file while uploading programmatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage to store images. I noticed that you can upload multiple files but I couldn't see anything about giving permissions to all files in one go. I give full access to the bucket but again all files inside it do not obtain the same permissions and I have to give one by one. I have also implemented a handler to upload files programmatically. Any ideas how to give full access to my images while uploading? Please see code below, I am using Spring MVC controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gcs/userimages/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws   IOException {
      GcsService gcsService =
                   GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
    //  GcsFileOptions go = new GcsFileOptions(Builder.);
      GcsFileOptions options = new   GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/png").build();
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
        gcsService.createOrReplace(getFileName(req), options);
    //outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content));
    copy(req.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
  }

  private GcsFilename getFileName(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String[] splits = req.getRequestURI().split("/", 4);
    if (!splits[0].equals("") || !splits[1].equals("gcs")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URL is not formed as expected. " +
          "Expecting /gcs/<bucket>/<object>");
    }
    return new GcsFilename(splits[2], splits[3]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#default)

**Default Object ACLs**

> Every bucket has a default object ACL and this ACL is applied to all objects uploaded to that bucket without a predefined ACL.

So, if you edit the *Default Object ACLs* to whatever you need, every files uploaded in that bucket will get the default ACLs

Read the documentation for the available methods to edit those parameters: **Changing default object ACLs**

You can also use the [JSON APIs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/defaultObjectAccessControls) where you can use [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1beta2/) to do your tests

Comment: I tried that. I gave all users read access to the bucket, but when I upload a file either manually through gcs admin or programmatically the file itself does not inherit permissions.

Comment: Buckets have two different types of ACL. There's the bucket ACL, which is access to the bucket, but there's also the bucket's "default object" ACL, which is the ACL that will be applied to objects created in that bucket by default. Giving read access to the bucket doesn't affect the default object ACL.

Comment: @Brandon Yarbrough - Thanks, do you know how to edit the default bucket object ACL before uploading files?

Comment: Yes, using the JSON API, it's the [DefaultObjectAccessControls](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/defaultObjectAccessControls) object. Since you only need to do it once, you may find it useful to set it using gsutil: "gsutil defacl set public-read gs://bucketname"

Comment: Thanks all guys. I used JSON API and also downloaded gsutil and everything looks good

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an approach on that. I just changed the code to :

```
GcsFileOptions options = new   GcsFileOptions.Builder().acl("public_read").mimeType("image/png").build();
```

Now every time a file is uploaded everyone has read access.